# Assigning 2D variable sized arrays

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to store a 2D array of variable length c-strings into a struct so I can transmit and rebuild it over a network socket.

The plan is to have rows and cols, which is in the header of the packet, help me read the variable size lens and arr that come after. I believe I must be syntactically writing the pointers incorrectly or there's some kind of aux pointer I need use when setting them into the struct.

```
struct STORAGE {
   int rows;     // hdr
   int cols;     // hdr
   int** lens;
   const char*** arr;
}

// code
int rows = 11;
int cols = 2;

int lens[rows][cols];
const char* arr[rows][cols];
// ... fill with strings ...
// ... along with lens ...

STORAGE store;
store.rows = rows;
store.cols = cols;
store.lens = lens;
store.arr = arr;
```

I get these errors when compiling this code:

> error: invalid conversion from `int` to `int**` [-fpermissive]
>
> error: cannot convert `const char* [11][2]` to `const char***' in assignment

I come from mostly a Java background, but I do understand how pointers work and such. The syntax of this one is just a little sideways for someone with my background (mostly write java/c++ and less c). Any suggestions?

Note: the reason why I'm not using more complex types like strings, maps, vectors, etc is that I need to transmit the structure over the network (ie pointers to the heap won't work if they have variable sizes). It must be low-level arrays unless someone can offer a better solution.

Comment: `***` ALARM! ALARM! BEEP WHEEP BEEP. ALARM!

Comment: [Why can't we use double pointer to represent two dimensional arrays?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4470950)

Comment: Seriously, why don't you use [regular standard c++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) instead?

Comment: Is there a good reason to use c-style arrays?

Comment: Don't be a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).  Seriously, just use `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` instead of that pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer monstrosity.

Comment: Pointers aren't arrays. Your `STORAGE` doesn't actually store anything! The same reason you've decided not to use containers is the same reason this approach won't work (indirection is indirection no matter the allocation method used). Plus you can't assign arrays, and `int**` and `int[w][h]` are unrelated types (perhaps this is unintuitive). I would just go with the expressive method and come up with a serialisation function. Is that an option?

Comment: @MilesBudnek As OP states, that won't work well with network transmissions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh, yeah, didn't see the note at the end of the OP.  Of course, anything with pointers can't be directly transmitted over a network, so that's perhaps a bit misguided.

Comment: Miles, and the rest, note, my comment about the sizes being part of the header which is transmitted first.. I am aware that the entire struct won't be transmitted because it contains pointers, but the size of the remainng data will be predictable after the header. I cant use vecot or string because those are NOT FIXED sizes. There is no way to predict how much space will be transmitted in order to build the data back up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It must be low-level arrays unless someone can offer a better solution.

A unidimensional `std::vector<int>` or `std::vector<uint8_t>` already provides you with a *low-level* array allocated contiguously using the `std::vector::data()` member.

Any further dimensions you need might be determined by sectioning that data properly. For network transmission, you would need to provide the necessary sectioning dimensions up front, and sent the data afterwards.

Something like:

```
Transmit num_of_dimensions
Transmit dim_size_1, dim_size_2, dim_size_3, ...
Transmit data

Receive num_of_dimensions
Loop Receiving dimension sizes
Receive dim_size_1 * dim_size_2 * dim_size_3 * ... of data
```

What I'd probably have to handle such situation is a class / struct looking like:

```
template<typename T>
class MultiDimensional {
    size_t num_dimensions_; // If known in advance can be made a template parameter also
    std::vector<size_t> dimension_sizes_;
    std::vector<T> data_;
public:
    const T& indexing_accessor(...) const;
    T& indexing_accessor(...);
    std::vector<uint8_t> render_transmision_data();
    // construct from transmission data
    MultiDimensional(std::vector<uint8_t>& transmission_data); 
};
```

Comment: This breaks my convention of having to read bytes from the socket right into my struct. Using vectors wont work because they grow past what data is stored in them. Also, C++ strings wont work because they point to the heap and also grow.

Comment: @ComputerEngineer88 I am pretty sure such thing would work well in any networking environment supposed you already use `htonl()` `ntohl()` functions correctly to make these numbers network transparent. Your self constructed convention probably isn't the best solution for that problem. Your multidimensional array approach won't work well anyways.

Comment: I ended up using something similar to your transmit/receive order. size, data, size, data and used a higher level object with growing memory inside the struct. As long as I serialize and deserialize the same way, it works. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @ComputerEngineer88 Wow, three month later. But well ;)

Comment: 3 months of working code. giving credit where it's due :)

Answer (score 0):

Using low-level stuff like arrays won't help you much, it's too complicated already. Also, it can get you in a hell of compatibility problems (like thinking about byte-order).

Unless you have very strict performance constraints, use a solution designed specifically for networking instead: [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). This is a bit of overkill for your case, but it scales well in case you need to add anything.

To use protocol buffers, you first define "messages" (structures) in a `.proto` file, then compile them to C++ with Proto Compiler.

You define your message like this (this is a complete `.proto` file):

```
syntax = "proto2";

package test;

message Storage {
   message Row {
       repeated string foo = 1;
   }
   repeated Row row = 1;
}
```

There is no direct support for 2D arrays, but an array of arrays will do just fine (`repeated` means that there can be multiple values in given field, it is basically a vector). You could add fields for array size, if you need quick access to them, but checking the size of repeated fields should suffice in most practical cases.

What you get is a class that have all the fields you need, takes care of memory management, and have [a bunch of methods to serialize and deserialize](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial#parsing-and-serialization).

The C++ code gets a little longer in places, as you need to use getters and setters, but it should be well offset by the fact that you never need to think about serialization - it happens all by itself.

Example use of this thing in C++ could look like this:

```
#include "test.pb.h"  // Generated from test.proto

using ::test::Storage;

int main() {
  Storage s;
  Storage::Row* row1 = s.add_row();
  row1->add_foo("foo 0,0");
  row1->add_foo("foo 0,1");
  Storage::Row* row2 = s.add_row();
  row2->add_foo("foo 1,0");
  row2->add_foo("foo 1,1");

  assert(s.row_size() == 2);
  assert(s.row(0).foo_size() == 2);

  s.PrintDebugString();  // prints to stdout
}
```

In the result, you get this output (note that this is debug output, not real serialization):

```
row {
  foo: "foo 0,0"
  foo: "foo 0,1"
}
row {
  foo: "foo 1,0"
  foo: "foo 1,1"
}
```

For completeness: in above example the source files were `test.proto` and `test.cpp`, compiled using:

```
protoc --cpp_out=. test.proto
g++ test.cpp test.pb.cc -o test -lprotobuf
```

Comment: Frax, I have considered using Google's protocol buffers, but my application needs to be as lean and native as possible since it is running on an embedded system. This doesn't solve my question, but it is something I already went over.

Comment: In that case you I guess you can take a look at [nanopb](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb) (unless you considered it as well). I have never used it, but it seems like it's worth a shot.